# Google Sheets Data Validation has error that says "Input must fall within specified range" even though it does

Tags: validation, google-sheets, format, dropdown

I have a pretty complex google sheet, at least for me, that has 2 dependent dropdown menus. For some reason my second dropdown menu is returning an error.

[image: Picture showing error on dropdown]

I don't know why it's returning this error because that value DOES fall within the specified range.

[image: Picture showing data validation range]

As you can see the range has each of those values. Why would I be getting this error?

Below is a link to a copy of the google sheet I'm working on. I set it to viewer only so no one messes it up before you can look at it. Just make a copy of it and see if you can diagnose what I'm missing.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GJhUw58mwj-DbPSnWsxpgqK8aIKy8v8xsOC4unrz7_4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

The **format** of your cell is **wrong**.
Change it from `Plain text` to `Automatic`

[image]

Comment: This fixed it. Interestingly enough this was the first thing I tried when diagnosing my problem except for the other way around. One was Plain Text and the other was Automatic. So I made them both Plain Text and it didn't work still. I guess I should have tried to make them both Automatic. Worked like a charm and I no longer get an error. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

either the above or change `MasterDataValidation!M1` to:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(IF('Legrabox Drawer Cutlist'!D6=FALSE,
 INDEX($A$11:$E$16,,MATCH('Legrabox Drawer Cutlist'!F6, $A$10:$E$10, )),
 INDEX($B$20:$E$24,,MATCH('Legrabox Drawer Cutlist'!F6, $B$19:$E$19, )))&""))
```

[image]

[image]